# SELECT rows based on distinctiveness of two columns

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Lets say we have the following table

```
orderId  productId   orderDate              amount    
1        2           2017-01-01 20:00:00    10 
1        2           2017-01-01 20:00:01    10 
1        3           2017-01-01 20:30:10    5 
1        4           2017-01-01 22:31:10    1
```

where the first 2 rows are known to be duplicates (e.g. result of faulty software), because **orderId**+**productId** must form an **unique key**

I want to remove this type of duplicates. How to do this in the most efficient way?

If there wasn't the orderDate one second difference, we could use

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `table`
```

With the difference, one could use groupby:

```
SELECT `orderId`,`productId`,MIN(`orderDate`),MIN(`amount`)
FROM table
GROUP BY `orderId`,`productCode`
```

I find the latter command very tiring to type if there is a lot of columns. What are the other options?

**UPDATE:** I am using [Snowflake](https://www.snowflake.net/).

Comment: Which DBMS you are using ?

Comment: What to do if the amount differs? How to decide which of the two entries to keep?

Comment: Do you want to delete duplicate records from the table or only not select them?

Comment: Can you not do SELECT DISTINCT orderId, productId FROM table

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Not select them is enough

Comment: But how to chose which row to return?

Comment: @Phil3992 I want to keep the entire row

Comment: @jarlh - let's say there is only one column in which the difference can occur (date column in our example)

Comment: Yes, so same key, different date. Which date to show?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner let's say MIN

Comment: Then do `GROUP BY`, with `MIN()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your dbms supports `ROW_NUMBER` window function then

```
select * from 
(
select row_number()Over(Partition by orderId,productId order by orderDate asc) as rn,*
From yourtable 
)a
Where Rn = 1
```

Comment: Looks like OP is using MySQL.

Comment: @jarlh: at least MariaDB is about to arrive in the 21st century: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-1020-release-notes/

Comment: @jarlh - True.. didn't see the back ticks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` to exclude records that have a better match:

```
select * from mytable
where not exists
(
  select *
  from mytable other
  where other.orderid   = mytable.orderid
    and other.productid = mytable.productid
    and other.orderdate < mytable.orderdate
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems as if you want to get the records with the minimum `orderdate` value within the records with common `orderid` and `productid`. This can be expressed in  SQL as follows:

```
select * from mytable t where t.orderdate = 
  (select min(t2.orderdate)
   from mytable t2
   where t2.orderid = t.orderid 
     and t2.productid = t.productid);
```

Note that this query cannot eliminate exact duplicates in columns `orderid`, `productid`, and `orderdate`; but this has actually not been requested.

Answer (score 0):

Pரதீப் 's answer is good, but Snowflake now supports the QUALIFY function which allows you to avoid the sub-select/WHERE pattern and do it one layer, so your SQL could be written

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY orderId, productId ORDER BY orderDate) = 1
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

and with the dummy data loaded by VALUES

```
SELECT * FROM VALUES  
    (1, 2, '2017-01-01 20:00:00', 10),
    (1, 2, '2017-01-01 20:00:01', 10),
    (1, 3, '2017-01-01 20:30:10', 5),
    (1, 4, '2017-01-01 22:31:10', 1) 
    t(orderId, productId, orderDate, amount)
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY orderId, productId ORDER BY orderDate) = 1
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

we get the desired rows:

| ORDERID | PRODUCTID | ORDERDATE | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2017-01-01 20:00:00 | 10 |
| 1 | 3 | 2017-01-01 20:30:10 | 5 |
| 1 | 4 | 2017-01-01 22:31:10 | 1 |

### What not to do:

I see in the comments to use GROUP BY/MIN, but that will give to the minimin values across each column, and not take all the values from the matching row, like in the altered example, the first row is the earliest (1,2) row, but the min of amount is 9 from the other row.

```
SELECT orderId, productId, min(orderDate), min(amount) FROM VALUES  
    (1, 2, '2017-01-01 20:00:00', 10),
    (1, 2, '2017-01-01 20:00:01', 9),
    (1, 3, '2017-01-01 20:30:10', 5),
    (1, 4, '2017-01-01 22:31:10', 1) 
    t(orderId, productId, orderDate, amount)
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

| ORDERID | PRODUCTID | ORDERDATE | AMOUNT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2017-01-01 20:00:00 | 9 |
| 1 | 3 | 2017-01-01 20:30:10 | 5 |
| 1 | 4 | 2017-01-01 22:31:10 | 1 |